# Optimize render React Components depends on props

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I've got a component that renders depends on props I pass to it. Previously I used logical operators OR, but when becomes more props it looks ugly, and I switched all these to array with `Array.prototype.some` method. Do you know how to do it better or some best practice for that?

Before:

```
<Wrapper>
{(props1 || props2 || props3 || props4) && <Component/>}
</Wrapper>
```

After:

```
<Wrapper>
{[props1, props2, props3, props4].some(x => x) && <Component/>}
</Wrapper>
```

Comment: The only really minor modification I can think of is `.some(Boolean)`, but that's not an improvement. The information is scarce, however. Why do you 4 props for this?

Comment: The latter may look better, but the former is more performant as you dont need to create an array on each render and then iterate that array. I suggest using the first approach.

Comment: @OriDrori if any of these props will be passed I will render the component if none of these  I won't

Comment: @PalaniichukDmytro - I know what the end result is :) why do you need 4 props to be passed to begin with? What are this props exactly?

Comment: @OriDrori I see, actually it tow bool props and two functions, depends on it I show it inside component some buttons

Comment: Do this props get passed to the <Component/>? Do you use them in any other way in the <Wrapper />?

Comment: Only one bool I use outside Wrapper rest of them only inside

Answer (score 1):

depending on how the props are passed you could use a spread operateur

```
<Wrapper>
{...this.props.someArray.some(x => x) && <Component/>}
</Wrapper>
```

there is no one solution to the problem however, you could use Redux (and its alternatives) to manage the global rendering of a component via the global store. If your concern is more about having to use arrays of props to render then it could be good at looking at other data structures such as Maps.

The react philosophy tries to push for reusable components were possible. The best way is to use stateless components as much as possible and handled all the rendering logic in a smart parent component. So maybe look at putting the logic in the parent component.